# How to check the value in redis stored by spring boot @cacheable

Tags: redis

Sorry, I'm new to the combination of `redis` and `springboot @cacheable`.

I just stored some data with `springboot @cacha` in redis and then I tried to check the value from `redis-cli`.
However, I couldn't get the value with the key, it's always null even though the API can get the value from the redis.

Here is my code:

```
// conde in springboot controller
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
@Cacheable(value = "dataList")
public SomeObject getDataList(SomeParameters someParameters){ ... }
```

```
# code I used to check the data in redis
$ 127.0.0.1:6379>keys *
1) "dataList::SimpleKey []"
$ 127.0.0.1:6379>llen dataList
0
$ 127.0.0.1:6379>type dataList
none
$ 127.0.0.1:6379>type dataList::SimpleKey
none
```

I'm wondering how to get value with that key above...
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just figured it out on my own. It turns to be that entire value inside of double quotation is the key!

So the correct way to get the value is:

```
$ 127.0.0.1:6379>keys *
1) "dataList::SimpleKey []"

$ 127.0.0.1:6379>get "dataList::SimpleKey []"
```

Hope it could help you if you had the same confusion!